# How to replace a single quote with double quotes in ADF dynamic expressions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to replace single quote in a string with double quote using replace function with data factory expressions.

For example, replace single quote in the following string

hello'world ---> hello''world

```
@replace(pipeline().parameters.tst,''','''')
```

The above code is not working. Need help in fixing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a new parameter with the value `'` (single quote). You can look at the following demonstration for reference.

- I have taken 2 parameters, `text` with the value `hello'world` and `replace_char` with the value `'`.

[image]

- I used a `set variable` activity to store the output of the `replace()` function (for demonstration) into variable named `output` (String). Now, I modified the value as:

```
@replace(pipeline().parameters.text,pipeline().parameters.replace_char,'"')
```

[image]

- This successfully helps in replacing a single quote with double quote character.

[image]

**NOTE:** The `\` in the `output` variable value indicates that the `"` is to be considered as a character inside the string value.

Answer (score 0):

Use two single quotes to escape a ' character in string functions.

For example, expression `@concat('Baba', '''s ', 'book store')` will return below result.

```
Baba's book store
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#escaping-single-quote-character